# Creating a project with just POJO beans

Tags: java, maven, project

Is it ok to have a Project full of just POJO beans (just getters and setters)? The reason is that I'm breaking my project into multiple smaller ones, and they all consume these POJOs. For example, I have a parser (JSON, XML, Excel etc.) that parses the input (Stream, reader, generic etc.) to multiple POJOs. These POJOs are consumed by another Project. So both the projects are dependent on the POJOs. Is it advisable to have the POJOs alone in a separate project, and add the project as a dependency in the Projects that consume them?

Comment: Thanks, guys.. cleared my doubts..

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so is it advisable to have the POJOs alone in a separate project, and add the project as a dependency in the Projects that consume them

Yes. This kind of module structuring is quite common in a multi-module project

A very common use case for such intermediate domain model projects is when two systems communicate with each other, say through something like a message oriented middleware such as JMS. Here, the message sent between the two systems can be a complex object and both systems share the same object structure (and thus a seperate jar that only contains these POJOs).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's fine. It's simply a shared dependency between two disparate modules. It's a simple library.